# chartjs or morris.js in PDF generated from blade view - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, charts, dompdf

I would like to use chartjs or morris.js while generating PDF from blade view. I'm using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. But I see that it is not rendering script files. Is there any other alternative way to use charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for few days, I got to make it work with **spatie-browsershot**. This helped me to create a pdf from html and also supported various charts. It is very easy to use and also efficient.

[Link](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot)

Comment: is it nodejs package? I am looking for laravel vendor for this. Do you have any idea, where PDF cab be saved from html with chart.js chart.

Comment: Yes. I used this package with laravel to generate charts and save in pdf